# Activating elementor plugin kills my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, elementor

Activating Elementor in order to use it as a page builder I will visit my site to edit it and the site simply does not load, saying the 'site can't be reached - the connection was reset' and the console displays:

```
(index):6772 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

Upon deactivating Elementor from the dashboard the site will load again like normal.

I am running wordpress on local host using bitnami.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 – Delete launch.json file in VSCode**
The most common reason is when you try to debug the application using the wrong configuration in the VScode launch.json this error would occur.

The best way is to delete the launch.json file and run the application and see if this fixes the issue. In most cases, this would solve the error.

**Solution 2 – Check the port and HTTPS configuration in launch.json**

There are times that the port you are using may not be opened or it might be used by another application and when you try to run the application you will get this error.
Configure the same port in launch.json for debugging purposes, providing a different port also will lead to this error.

Also, ensure that you are using the correct protocol and the same is configured in the launch.json. Sometimes the application is configured to run using HTTP but you might be running using HTTPS.

Try checking your URL, routes, and settings and ensure the correct protocol is used everywhere.

**Solution 3 – Run the application in VsCode**

Instead of launching your application using the option “Launch Chrome against localhost“, rather set your application name for launching.

The issue can be resolved by deleting the launch.json file in the VSCode and also ensuring the port is opened and configured properly in the launch.json and the right protocol(http/https) is used to browse the application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug situation like this is to (1) deactivate one by one the plugin except the elementor and see what is the other plugin that cause some conflict with the elementor, (2) try updating and changing the theme of the website and see if the conflict still persist. If option 2 is not working on your situation, you might want to disable all the plugins and activate it one by one.

Comment: All plugins were disabled at the posting of this question, only elementor poses the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).